# Find Min and Max from Text File - Python

Tags: python

I need to find the minimum and max value from this list of data. I can get the maximum but the minimum. The text file has a lot of data so I decided to upload it here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/u5ov5zij9v5fumt/project05.data.txt?dl=0

Input

```
try:
    file_name = input("Enter the name of an input file ")
    input_file = open( file_name, "r" )
    header=input_file.readline()
    count=0
    total=0  
    largest_num=0
    smallest_num=0
    michigan=""
    for line in input_file:
        output=float(line[67:71].rstrip())

        total += output
        count +=1
        if largest_num<= output:
            largest_num = output

        if smallest_num >= output:
            smallest_num = output

        if line[0:17].rstrip() == "Michigan":
            state=(line[0:17])
            number=(line[67:75])
    print("\nState with the smallest MMR vaccation rate:")
    print("   with a rate of")
    print("\n State with largest MMR vaccination rate:" )
    print("   with a rate of")

    print("\nThe calculated average vaccination rate is",round(total/count,1))
    print("")
    print("Michigan MMR vaccination rate is", number)
    input_file.close()
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print("Error: file not found")
        file_name = input("Enter the name of an input file ")
        input_file = open( file_name, "r" )
```

Comment: What does this have to do with reading and/or writing a file?  What is the actual issue?

Comment: Please do also try to fix your indentation :)

Comment: Trying to find find the min and max of the MMR vaccination rate(see txt file)

Comment: You never even print `largest_num` or `smallest_num`; how do you know they don't have the right values?

Comment: You initialize `smallest_num` to 0, so only negative values will change it.

Comment: Your code looks like it tries to read a file, but it doesn't seem to write anything.  How do you know the problem--whatever the problem is--has to do with reading a file? (I only ask to try to get you to think about how to solve your own problem--these are questions you should ask yourself when debugging a programming problem.)

Comment: I  took it out for now because there is some other stuff I have to print, but I printed largest_num and i got 96.3 which is correct @jwodder.

Comment: I'm not trying to write to any file, I incorrectly named my question originally @Iguananaut

Answer (score 2, accepted):

List comprehensions are your friends.

```
numbers = [float(line[67:71].rstrip()) for line in input_file]

largest_num = max(numbers)
smallest_num = min(numbers)
total = sum(numbers)
count = len(numbers)
```

Comment: you dont need to strip for float to work it ignores whitespace