# Find the line with the min and max value and your line number from text file (Get Value Error Float Type)

Tags: python, string, type-conversion, row, typeerror

I have a file 1.txt containing words and symbols on some lines while on other lines I have only numbers, and never no numbers are on the same line where words and symbols are.

```
FOO >
1.0
BAR <
0.004
FOO FOO <
0.000004
BAR BAR <
```

What I need is to analyze only the lines that have numbers, and then compare the numbers found and print the maximum value and minimum value.

In addition it is important that I know the line number (instead index) of the minimum value and the maximum value.

I tried to solve this looking at some questions like

[Find Min and Max from Text File - Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28618342/find-min-and-max-from-text-file-python) e [How to Find Minimum value from *.txt file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53592197/how-to-find-minimum-value-from-txt-file/53592830)

But, for example, when I run the code

```
import csv
rows = []
with open('1.txt', mode='r') as infile:
    reader = csv.reader(infile, delimiter=" ")
    for row in reader:  # each row is a list
        rows.append(row)
minimus = min(rows, key=lambda x: float(x[0]))
print(minimus)
```

I have bumped into the following error

> ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'FOO'

How could I escape the lines that have symbols and words and just analyze the lines that have numbers, also obtaining the indicator of the lines with the minimum and maximum value?

I could extract all the rows that contains only numbers to a new file (for example using regex), but I would need to know the previous/after line to the line that the minimum value was found, then any line extraction would increase the number of steps of the analysis in which I am involved because I would have to return to analyze the original 1.txt file.

Note: I am inexperienced in Python compared to a frequent user of this language, but I think it is something simple for stackoverflow Questions list, and I suspect that perhaps this issue has already been answered. But as I already looked for some satisfactory question and I did not find it so I'm doing my own question.

Comment: Verify that the current row is a number before appending it to rows.

Comment: @JohnGordon I'm not sure how to do this, but then I'll research.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible approach without the need for any extra modules

**Code:**

```
def is_float(x):
  try:
    float(x)
    return True
  except:
    return False

with open('url1.txt', 'r') as myfile:
  lines = myfile.readlines()
  
nums = [x for x in lines if is_float(x)]
my_min = min(nums)
my_max = max(nums)

print('Max: ', my_max, 'line number: ', lines.index(my_max)+1)
print()
print('Min: ', my_min, 'line number: ', lines.index(my_min)+1)
```

**Input:**

```
FOO >
1.0
BAR <
0.004
FOO FOO <
0.000004
BAR BAR <
```

**Output:**

```
Max:  1.0
 line number:  2

Min:  0.000004
 line number:  6
```

**Explanation:**

1. write a function to check if a string can be converted to float, this can be done by using `try` statement and `float()`
2. filter floats from lines read from file
3. find the min and max values
4. find indices of min and max in list of lines using `list.index(<value>)`
5. Add 1 to indices to get line number as indices starts from zero

Comment: Its solution worked very well, and even was able to work in the presence of comma between the words, I only altered `lines.Index (my_max))` to `lines.index (my_max) +1)` to correct the value of the line index printing when 1.txt has a comma between the words.

Comment: Also changed `lines.index (my_min))` for `( lines.index (my_min) + 1)) ` to correct line index printing.Also changed `lines.index (my_min))` for `( lines.index (my_min) + 1)) ` to correct line index printing.

Comment: @YaacovNNNNM but why should you add 1, index start from zero so isn't the output already correct?

Comment: I did not change your code in my tests just added +1 to the variable I quoted in the above comment. But how can I change so Index beg about 1? For when there is a presence of commas between words, the indiff ends is printed as for example 16 instead of 17.

Comment: @YaacovNNNNM could you explain what you expect as index, I thought it was the line number

Comment: But it's exactly the number of the line I expect.

Comment: see please https://imgur.com/a/EnmCLtD and https://imgur.com/a/gN1h5of.

Comment: Understood i ment i thought it was row index, the simplest way to get line number would be to add 1 so I'll edit my answer, also I think you should specify you want the line number not the index. As you know indices in programming starts from zero.

Comment: I'm sorry, I had a notion of Index to start from zero, but I did not realize the extent of its importance in my question.

Comment: @YaacovNNNNM It's ok, I've updated the answer I hope it gets you the result you want.

Answer (score 1):

This might be overkill, but what immediately came to my mind is *RegEx* (*Reg*ular *Ex*pressions), using the `re` library.

Here's the RegEx you would use for a float: `^[1-9]\d*(\.\d+)?$`. So we can implement this code:

```py
import csv
import re

rows = []
with open('1.txt', mode='r') as infile:
    reader = csv.reader(infile, delimiter=" ")
    for row in reader:  # each row is a list
        if bool(re.match(r'^[1-9]\d*(\.\d+)?$', row): rows.append(row)
minimus = min(rows, key=lambda x: float(x[0]))
print(minimus)
```

What I changed:
I added `if bool(re.match...`, resulting in `rows` only getting appended to under the circumstance that `row` is only a float (or integer).

Comment: I get follow error while running your solution: `File "<ipython-input-4-dd119e2358f1>", line 8
    if bool(re.match(r'^[1-9]\d*(\.\d+)?$', row): rows.append(row)
                                                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Answer (score 0):

```
import csv
rows = []
with open('1.txt', mode='r') as infile:
    reader = csv.reader(infile, delimiter=" ")
    for row in reader:
        if not row[0].isalpha():
            rows.append(row[0])
    print(rows)
minimus = min(rows, key=lambda x: float(x[0]))
print(minimus)
```

Incorporate an `if` statement to check if the `row[0]` is not an `alpha`

> [str.isalpha()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isalpha) Return True if all characters in the string are
> alphabetic and there is at least one character, False otherwise

Comment: Doesn't `str.isalpha` include numbers?

Comment: you mean `str.isalnum`??

Answer (score 0):

I suggest a simple solution by collecting all numbers and their indices using a try except statement. After the number and indices are collected in two lists you can find the min and max by for instance making use of the numpy package.

```
import numpy as np

numbers, indices = [],[]
with open("1.txt") as my_text_file:
    for i, line in enumerate( my_text_file.readlines() ):
        try:
            numbers.append( float(line) )
            indices.append( i )
        except:
            pass

maxvalue = np.max( numbers )
minvalue = np.min( numbers )
maxindx  = indices[ np.argmax( numbers ) ]
minindx  = indices[ np.argmin( numbers ) ]

print("The maximum value is found at line "+str(maxindx)+" with the value "+str(maxvalue))
print("The minimum value is found at line "+str(minindx)+" with the value "+str(minvalue))
```

For the provided 1.txt file thisproduces theprint out

```
The maximum value is found at line 1 with the value 1.0                                                                 
The minimum value is found at line 5 with the value 4e-06
```

Cheers

Comment: Its solution has a great advantage by allowing passing lines with commas, otherwise each space between commas and words would be considered a new column.

Comment: Its solution worked very well, and even was able to work in the presence of comma between the words, I only altered `maxindx  = indices[ np.argmax( numbers ) ]` to `maxindx  = indices[ np.argmax( numbers ) ] + 1` (also for `minindx..`) to correct the value of the line index printing when 1.txt has a comma between the words.

Comment: as Abhi_J explained me I did not specify that I wish the line indice instead of index, I ask you forgiveness for my mistake.