# Find the minimum between two consecutive occurrence of numbers and repeat the process to the end of the file

Tags: python, regex, unix, line, min

Having a 0.txt file below:

```
Report "Curve ABC" for bread and milk on New Mexico City:

Bread and mil price by markets:

milk on market "Onlyfoods"
10
bread on market "Onlyfoods"
23
milk on market "spassus"
30
bread on market "spassus"
4
bread on market "chaim"
56
milk on market "chaim"
96
bread on market "house green"
7
milk on market "house green"
0.8
```

I would like to compare the first line where there are any number with the second consecutive line where there are also some number, and then determine the minimum value between them and print the number of the line where the minimum value is. I would like to repeat the same process for the third and fourth occurrence of some number, that is, compare them and get the minimum between them, and so on.

For example: It would be necessary to compare 10 and 23 and its minimum would be 10 and the line number would be 6; By continuing, between 20 and 4 the minimum is 4 and the line number would be 12.

The output file should be something like:

```
minimun is between 10 and 23 is 10 in line 6

minimun is between 30 and 4 is 4 in line 12
.
.
...
```

I have made a similar question but got many downvotes and I do not understand why this issue is not useful being that no one has shown me some other issue already posted here in the stackoverflow.

I could combine this issue,  "[calculate the difference between number lines file](https://www.unix.com/unix-for-dummies-questions-and-answers/110446-calculate-difference-between-numbers-lines-file.html)", with this question, [Find the line with the min and max value and your line number from text file (Get Value Error Float Type)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66845255/find-the-line-with-the-min-and-max-value-and-your-line-number-from-text-file-ge/66845449?noredirect=1#comment118161608_66845449), but I have not been able to understand how to do this.

**EDIT UPDATE 1:**

Alternative partial pseudocode:

A starting point using UNIX/REGEX/AWK: Basically I should: 1 - Extract the line number of each instance of numeric value and save to a 1.txt file in a list vertically; 2 - Extract the numeric value of each instance and save in 2.txt in a vertical list and then apply the solution given [here](https://www.unix.com/unix-for-dummies-questions-and-answers/110446-calculate-difference-between-numbers-lines-file.html) to find the minimum between each pair of consecutive rows and save the minimum values (in order as extracted) in a file 3.txt; 3 - So I should append or paste on the left or right of each respective 1.txt line using a separator such as a comma or `:` each line of 3.txt and save in a 4.txt file.

Comment: 1. tag this with the language you want to see the answer in, 2. show your attempt (this is very basic, please at least try) 3. It is a strange request, try to explain a business use case or other reason for this, even if it is a homework question (which this looks like) explain that and the topic you were trying to revise.

Comment: You said you have _tried without any effective results_ so you need to include that effort in this. Using the questions you have cited make this even easier, so show your code and we might see where you went wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the file, create an empty variable, check if the string is a number, compare and find the minimal value.

```
file = open("0.txt")
m = None
results = []
indexes = []

for i,d in enumerate(file):
    try:
        results.append(float(d))
        indexes.append(i+1)
    except ValueError:
        pass

for r in range(1,len(results),2):
    
    if results[r - 1] < results[r]:
         print("minimum between",results[r-1],"and",results[r],"is",results[r-1],"line",indexes[r])

    else:
        print("minimum between",results[r-1],"and",results[r],"is",results[r],"line",indexes[r])
```

Comment: I would like to make your response work when the number of busy rows is an odd number, because in this case I am getting the error `if results[r] < results[r+1]:
IndexError: list index out of range`

Comment: @7beggars_nnnnm I edited the answer so it does not give you the ``IndexError`` when odd number of rows.

Comment: This worked smoothly now, and his response has been very clear.